# phonegap IOS, how to open a text message up and prefill it

Tags: ios, cordova

Is it possible to open the a text message up and prefill its body? (not send it) in ios phonegap?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an `<a>` tag

example:

```
<a href="sms://+3490322111?body=messagebody">
Send SMS</a>
```

or the [SMSComposer plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/iOS/SMSComposer)

Comment: Where is this use of the `<a>` tag documented?

Comment: Here the link to the w3c http://www.w3.org/TR/mwabp/